# CSS not applied relative to parent

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have a div with ID= **"outer"** inside a div whose ID is **"Container"**. I am trying to adjust outer div properties relative to parent i.e its width, height etc should be relative to `Container` div. I can't understand why it is not being applied. I know because of this reason, my menu is also not adjusting. Can please someone figure out mistake in my code? Thanks.

**HTML Code:**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
<img width="60%" alt="Logo" src="images/logo.jpg">
<div id="divHeader"><br /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
<input type="radio" value="Pages" checked="true" name="searchOpt">Pages
<input type="radio" value="Contact People" name="searchOpt"/>Contact People
<input type="button"  value="Search"/>
</div>
</header>
<!--pop up menu-->
<div id="outer">
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="nav1"><a href="">News & Events</a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="">Facilities</a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="">Research</a></li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="">Programmes</a></li>
    <li id="nav5"><a href="">Faculty</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
body { 

background-color:#0a1857;
}
#container
{
width:80%;
height:100%;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
position:fixed;
right:10%;
left:10%; 
}
header
{
width:100%;
height:15%;}

#divHeader
{
float:right;}

#outer
{
padding-left:20%;
width:80%;
height:40%;
background-image:url('images/image_31.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; }

#menu { 
position:relative;
top:220px;
right:170px;  
 width:108%;
height:20%;
text-align:center;
}
#menu a { 
display: block; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #3B5330;}
#menu a:hover { background: #B0BD97;}

#menu ul li {
font:12px georgia; 
list-style-type:none;
float: left; 
width: 20%; 
font-weight: bold; 
border-top: solid 1px #283923; 
border-bottom: solid 1px #283923; 
background: #979E71;}
#menu ul li a { 
font-weight: bold;
padding: 15px 10px;}
#menu li{ 
position:relative; 
float:left;}
#popup_menu ul li
{
float:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the main cause of my problem. My child div's were positioning and arranging themselves according to the Browser, not as that of parent because of:

`position:relative;`

I replaced it with:

`position:absolute;`

**Reference** from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)

> A **Relative Positioned** element is positioned relative to its normal position. The content of relatively positioned elements can be moved and overlap other elements, but the reserved space for the element is still preserved in the normal flow.Used for *element* to act as `Containers.`
>
> An **Absolute positioned** element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is `html` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try adding:

```
position: relative;
```

to the outer div?

Comment: I added but still not working. If I resize browser, outer div and menu both gets out of container.